# WPF C# - User Control that contains a TabControl as a child within a TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have a mainform which has a `tabControl`. I am attempting to create a `userControl` that can be added to a `tabItem`.
I aim to add a `tabControl` to the `userControl` however I get this error:

`'[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)[1].(2)'.`

The code is very simple within the userControl

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem>
                
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
```

How do I create the `userControl` so that it can contain a `tabControl` and then be added to the mainForm within a `tabItem`?

Comment: But the error is not related to the given code block, try to investigate the actual error source in your project, most probably in other files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UserControl1.xmal**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TabControl x:Name="tabControl">

        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**UserControl.cs**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public List<TabItem> TabItem { get; set; } = new List<TabItem>();
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        foreach (TabItem tabItems in TabItem)
            tabControl.Items.Add(tabItems);
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <local:UserControl1 Height="200" Width="200">
            <local:UserControl1.TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Tab1">
                    <TextBox/>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Tab2">
                    <TextBox/>
                </TabItem>
            </local:UserControl1.TabItem>
        </local:UserControl1>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In this case, the TextBox cannot be accessed through the x:Name="",

Because TextBox is a child of UserControl, not a child of MainWindow.