# WPF C# - Bind tab selection to treeView selection

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, treenode, tabitem

How do I bind a `tabItem` IsSelected property to a `treeView` Node selection via index or reference?

I want to be able to click on a `treenode` that will auto select a `tabItem` within a `tabControl`

Comment: Can you post some code around your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MainWindow.xmal**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        Height="600" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <TreeView Width="200" Height="200">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Items">
                <TreeViewItem x:Name="item1" Header="Tab1"/>
                <TreeViewItem x:Name="item2" Header="Tab2"/>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>
        <TabControl Height="200" Width="200">
            <TabItem Header="Tab1" IsSelected="{Binding ElementName=item1, Path=IsSelected}">
                <TextBox/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab2" IsSelected="{Binding ElementName=item2, Path=IsSelected}">
                <TextBox/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

combined with the previous question...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73563420/19891367

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
            Height="600" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <TreeView x:Name="treeView" Width="200" Height="200">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Tab1">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Tab1-1"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Tab1-2"/>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Tab2">
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>
        <local:UserControl1 Height="200" Width="200"
                            DataContext="{Binding ElementName=treeView}">
            <local:UserControl1.TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Tab1" IsSelected="{Binding Items[0].IsSelected}"/>

                <TabItem Header="Tab2" IsSelected="{Binding Items[1].IsSelected}"/>

                <TabItem Header="Tab1-1" IsSelected="{Binding Items[0].Items[0].IsSelected}"/>
            
                <TabItem Header="Tab1-2" IsSelected="{Binding Items[0].Items[1].IsSelected}"/>
            </local:UserControl1.TabItem>
        </local:UserControl1>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: That's really helpful thanks. It's binding a tab selection to a top level node, is it possible to bind the tab selection to the tree node and all of that tree node children?