# How do I bind a selected treeView Item within a user control to a tabControl in the MainWindow in WPF XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview

I have a `treeView` in a `userControl`:

```
        <TreeView x:Name="treeData"
            Background="#282828" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0,5,0,0"
                  SelectedValuePath="Uid">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Data1" x:Name="tData1" Uid="tabData1">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Data1-1" x:Name="tP1" Uid="Data1"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Data1-2" x:Name="tP2" Uid="Data1"/>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Data2" x:Name="tData2" Uid="tabData2"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Data3" x:Name="tData3" Uid="tabData3"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Data4" x:Name="tData4" Uid="tabData4"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Data5" x:Name="tData5" Uid="tabData5"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Data6" x:Name="tData6" Uid="tabData6"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Data7" x:Name="tData7" Uid="tabData7"/>
        </TreeView>
```

and a `TabControl` in the `MainWindow`:

```
                    <TabControl Grid.Column="1">
                        <TabItem Header="tabPs"
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem Header="tabPln"
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem Header="tabLn"
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem Header="tabAx"
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem Header="tabSp"
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem Header="tabPL">
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem Header="tabPk">
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem Header="tabAP"/>
                        </TabItem>
                    </TabControl>
```

I need to be able to have the correct tabItem selected when the user clicks on an Item in the `UserControl TreeView Item`. Is there a way to bind the selection of the treeView within the `UserControl` to select a tab on the MainWindow?

I'd previously asked a similar question here:
[WPF C# Bind multiple treeViewItems isSelected to tabItem isSelected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73565990/wpf-c-sharp-bind-multiple-treeviewitems-isselected-to-tabitem-isselected/73567163#73567163)
but it is aimed at a `userControl` that has the `tabControl` as opposed to the `TreeView` and I'm struggling to see how to bind it when the `TreeView` is in the `UserControl` and the `tabControl` is in the `MainWindow`

The user control is within the `MainWindow` within a grid:

```
        <views:TreeViewCntrl Grid.Column="1" x:Name="treeViewGeo">
        </views:TreeViewCntrl>
```

Comment: Is the `UserControl` located inside the `MainWindow`?

Comment: Yeah it is, I've updated the question to show

Answer (score 0):

Make the `treeData` field `internal` or expose it using a `public` property of the `UserControl`:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeData" x:FieldModifier="internal" ... />
```

You could then handle the `SelectedItemChanged` event for the `TreeView` of the ´UserControl` in the window:

```
treeViewGeo.treeData.SelectedItemChanged += (ss, ee) => 
{
    var selectedTreeViewItem = ee.NewValue as TreeViewItem;
    ... 
};
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this within xaml to keep the code behind clean?

Comment: Do what exactly? XAML is a *markup* language. Somewhere you need to define the "connection" between the `TreeView` and the `TabControl`.

Comment: Select the tab page based on the tree View selection. Similar to the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73562468/wpf-c-sharp-bind-tab-selection-to-treeview-selection which shows the binding between selected tree node and the tab page when the tabControl is in the User control, difference here being that with my setup the tree View is in the user control and tab control is in main window. But am being achieved in xaml and not using code behind

Comment: Based on what logic , i.e. how, do you connect a tree node and a tab page?